# Code editor Android app that supports code folding (expand/collapse code lines)

Tags: android, text-editor, plain-text, sublime-text

I'm looking for an Android code editor app that supports code folding (collapse/expand code lines).

**More Specifications:**

- Android version: 6.0.1 (Preferrably supports Android 4+ versions)
- Price: Any
- Other features:

  - Supported syntax coloring: Preferrably supports major web languages (HTML,CSS,JS,PHP), but not necessary.

**Reasearch Done:**
I know only one app that supports code folding, [920 Text Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jecelyin.editor.v2), suggested by [Izzy](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/49279/10492). The problem with this app is that it supports code folding only for content surrounded by braces. I need something that supports folding for indented content **whether it's surrounded by braces or not** like commonly-used Desktop code-editors.
Apps found to be not providing this feature:

- [Notepad++ for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.woop.notepad)
- [Quoda](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.henrythompson.quoda)
- [Our Code Editor Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ourcodeworld.ourcodeeditorfree)
- [QuickEdit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.edit)
- [DroidVim](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidvim)
- [Turbo Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maskyn.fileeditor)
- [ModPE IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.KillerBLS.modpeide)
- [DroidEdit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aor.droidedit)
- [Codeanywhere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codeanywhere.mobile)

Comment: Quoda is fine for me. What's the problem about it?

Comment: [VisiScript](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mneuroth.visiscript) can do that, but hasn't been updated for more than a year. [AndroxIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.entertain.androxide) is a bit newer. Best candidate probably is [920 Text Editor](https://www.appbrain.com/app/com.jecelyin.editor.v2) (also [available via my F-Droid repo](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/com.jecelyin.editor.v2)). Haven't tried any myself, hence just a comment.

Comment: @onurcano22 How could I do code folding in Quoda? I didn't find any option for this.

Comment: @Izzy I wasn't able to do code folding in Visiscript.
AndroxIDE only supports code folding over the Remote Editor which requires internet connection and isn't an Android based app.
920 Text Editor is the best candidate really I liked its UI. But I am not able to figure out how to do code folding within it.

Comment: @Omar See, that's why I wrote it as comment :) I just checked the app's descriptions. And 920 also says so on [it's Github decription](https://github.com/jecelyin/920-text-editor-v2). As I'm not using it myself, maybe you open an issue there to ask? I've just checked, nobody's asked that before – so it should either be obvious or noone is using that particular feature …

Comment: @Izzy I figured out how should it work. I need to select Highlight language first. Could you please add 920 Text Editor as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**920 Text Editor** should fit your needs:

- **Android version: 6.0.1 (Preferrably supports Android 4+ versions):** √ Android 4.0+
- **Price: Any:** √ free :)
- **Supported syntax coloring:** √ syntax highlighting supported
- **Preferrably supports major web languages (HTML,CSS,JS,PHP):** √ and much more: ASP, ActionScript, C/C++, C#, Erlang, Frink, HTML/XML/WML, CSS, Javascript, Java, JSP, Perl, PowerShell , PHP, Python, Shell/Bash, Lua, SQL, VB/VBS, Tcl, TeX/LaTeX, Verilog, AutoHotKey, AutoLisp, Pascal, Fortran, ColdFusion, VHDL …
- **code folding:** √ YES

[image: code-folding] [image: code-highlighting]
<sup>code folding and syntax highlighting in *920* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jecelyin.editor.v2); click images to enlarge)</sup>

*920 Text Editor* is available free of charge [at Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jecelyin.editor.v2) and, [being open source](https://github.com/jecelyin/920-text-editor-v2), also [at my F-Droid repo](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/com.jecelyin.editor.v2) (in the official repo you can only find the old version before it changed the package name).

Comment: The official repo is 2 years old. Why not update it? Someone could think Google does not allow your code for some nasty reason .

Comment: You need to ask that the developer. I cannot update the code, I'm no Android dev.